# Getting value component in python?

Tags: python, components

I cannot describe clearly because English is not my native language

If I input like this

> a = 4252

Then I want to take each number component, it should be like this

> a1=4; a2=2; a3=5; a4=2

How to do that in python?
If you know it has a similar question in stackoverflow, give me a link

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Ah I see, thank you very much

Comment: It would be much better to create a list rather than 4 independent variables related by their name only.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the integer to a string for easy iterability then get the int value of every character like this: `a1,a2,a3,a4 = [int(elem) for elem in str(a)]`

Comment: It works well, thanks